# Conditional return (no if or ternary)

Tags: javascript

I thought this would be very simple but I am unable to think of a way to conditionally return without using an `if` or ternary.

```
const example = (num1, num2) => {
  num1 === num2 && return 'equal';
  num1 !== num2 && return 'not equal';
}
```

This gives me an error saying `Unexpected token return`.

Comment: You can't return in an expression context. `return` must be a standalone statement. Don't be afraid of the conditional operator, it's very clean here. `return num1 === num2 ? 'equal' : 'not equal'`

Comment: This is a coding challenge where if statements and ternarys are not allowed

Answer (score 3):

If you *had* to avoid both the conditional operator and `if` statements, you could abuse `&&` and `||` to get to the logic you need, by prepending a `'not '` onto the `'equal'` returned if needed:

```js
const example = (num1, num2) => (
  ((num1 !== num2 && 'not ') || '') + 'equal'
);

console.log(example(2, 3));
console.log(example(3, 3));
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const example = (num1, num2) => num1 === num2 && 'equal' || 'not equal'
```

```js
const example = (num1, num2) => ['equal', 'not equal'][+(num1 !== num2)]
```

Comment: Better than mine!